# str.contains pandas returns 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' new to using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and been looking at this for a few days now, at a point where I need help.  I have the following code and it is throwing the following error:

> AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'contains'", 'occurred at index 239')

To be honest, I'm not sure where to start debugging, aside from the stuff I've tried. The culprit line is: `if row.display_name.contains("(EU)", case=False, regex=False)` but I'm not confident that line is the problem.  I've tried changing between contains and find but same error.  Any help or pointers would be really helpful

```
  if not discard_known_id.empty:
            discard_known_id["partner"] = discard_known_id.apply(
                lambda row: "Non-inventory user" if (pd.isna(row.partner))
                else (
                    "Non-inventory user (site known)"
                    if row.display_name.contains("(EU)", case=False, regex=False)
                    else row.partner
                ),
                axis=1,
            )
```

Tried this as well, in addition to find instead of contains

```
 if not discard_known_id.empty:
            discard_known_id["partner"] = discard_known_id.apply(
                lambda row: "Non-inventory user" if (pd.isna(row.partner))
                else (
                    "Non-inventory user (site known)"
                    if row.display_name.str.contains("(EU)", case=False, regex=False)
                    else row.partner
                ),
                axis=1,
            )
```

Comment: Try: `row.display_name.str.contains("(EU)", case=False, regex=False)` using the .str accessor. [see api docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually tried that before changing to the above. Same error. AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'contains'", 'occurred at index 239')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a contains function in Python that works the way you are trying to use it. There is a `str.contains` but that works on a series, not a string (hence your error). Instead you can use `in`.

I'd also add that I think the structure of your code is making your life unnecessarily difficult. Split out your logic into a separate function so you can more easily see what is happening. Here is a proposed solution:

```
def update_name(row):
    if pd.isna(row.partner):
        return "Non-inventory user"
    elif "(EU)" in row['display_name'].upper():
        return "Non-inventory user (site known)"
    else:
        return row.partner


if not discard_known_id.empty:
    discard_known_id["partner"] = discard_known_id.apply(update_name, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line to:

```
If "EU" in row.display_name.upper():
```

It looks like you are accessing a singular cell in which case I believe contains is only a pandas method and will not apply.

Answer (score 0):

yes str object does not have contains method in core python.

**Pandas** is a library which has very useful functionality called Series and DataFrame,

In Series class it  has attribute '**str**', through which you can use **contains** method.

**Example**:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the Series 
series1 = pd.Series(['New_Delhi', 'Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Agra', 'Lahore'])
sr[sr.str.contains('N')]
```

**Output**

```
0    New_Delhi
dtype: object
```

For more information about series.str contain method then visit official site of of pandas library:[pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)